# How to specify user defined text in report.html under "Message" header

Tags: python, robotframework

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, already answered by experts.
But is there a way to display my own text for each Testcase that will be shown under "Message" header in default report.html file?
I want to specify different user defined for each test cases and make them show in reports.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [BuiltIn](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) library has a keyword named [Set Test Message](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Message)

```
Set test message  Hello, world
```